# Swift.Streaming audio from url with error code -999 "cancelled"

Tags: swift, streaming, avaudioplayer

This is my code :

```
var playering = AVPlayer()


private func streamAudio(url: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {return}
    let playerItems = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    ReportVC.playering = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItems)
    ReportVC.playering.play()
}
```

and i call streamAudio in viewDidLoad() method like this :

```
self.streamAudio(url: "https://stage.careandcarers.com/file/get/0b710400-4454-4a46-9ed5-8a542f046ed8.m4a")
```

but i get this error in console :

> 2019-05-29 12:19:32.940076+0430 CC[13305:463451] Task <314067AD-725A-4C8E-820A-18D0A9351624>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://stage.careandcarers.com/file/get/0b710400-4454-4a46-9ed5-8a542f046ed8.m4a, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://stage.careandcarers.com/file/get/0b710400-4454-4a46-9ed5-8a542f046ed8.m4a, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask <314067AD-725A-4C8E-820A-18D0A9351624>.<1>"
>   ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <314067AD-725A-4C8E-820A-18D0A9351624>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
>   2019-05-29 12:19:32.943557+0430 CC[13305:460502] Task <314067AD-725A-4C8E-820A-18D0A9351624>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
>   2019-05-29 12:19:32.943604+0430 CC[13305:461457] TIC Read Status [5:0x0]: 1:57

what is the problem?

Comment: I tested on playground and it seems to work. Cases when this code= -999 happens are when dealing with asynchronous loading. Can you share `ReportVC` code? Because you're using the player you declared on top

Comment: ReportVC is very large and messy. which part do you want to see?

Comment: I wanted to see how you declare that `playering` there, because it might be possible that something gets deallocated before downloading audio content. I tried declaring `playering` locally when streaming audio and it works. So try declaring a new player inside streamAudio and tell me if it works

Comment: i changed the url to a sample MP3 Url and it works just fine. is it possible that m4a format is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
func streamPlay(streamUrl : string){
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( url:NSURL( string: streamUrl )! as URL )
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        player!.rate = 1.0;
        //isplay is a bool variable that indicate your stream playing is in process or not(default value = false)
        if isPlay{

            player!.pause()
            //playDemo is button that you use to stream play
            playDemo!.setImage(UIImage(named: "playBtn"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            playDemo!.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            isPlay = false

        }else{

            player!.play()
            playDemo!.setImage(UIImage(named: "media_pause"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            playDemo!.setTitle("play", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            isPlay = true
        }
}
```

in your viewDidLoad:

```
 let url = "https://stage.careandcarers.com/file/get/0b710400-4454-4a46-9ed5-8a542f046ed8.m4a"
 streamPlay(streamUrl : url)
```

Comment: same error, i think my code is fine. something else is wrong.

Comment: i changed the url to a sample MP3 Url and it works just fine. is it possible that m4a format is the problem?

Comment: maybe if they are encoded as AMR_NB they need to be encoded as AAC.